# Angular 5 ng-serve seeing old file

Tags: angular, npm

So, i  have an angular 5 app with this package.json:

```
{
"name": "Agencys",
"version": "0.0.1",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test... minimal project\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "echo \"Error: no lint... minimal project\" && exit 1",
    "e2e": "echo \"Error: no e2e... minimal project\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "npm run tsformat",
    "tsformat": "tsfmt -r",
    "extract": "ng2-translate-extract --clean --dir ./src --output ./src/js/i18n/en.json --sort --format=json && ng2-translate-extract --clean --dir ./src --output ./src/js/i18n/pt.json --sort --format=json && ng2-translate-extract --clean --dir ./src --output ./src/js/i18n/es.json --sort --format=json"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.4.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "primeng": "^5.0.2",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "typescript-formatter": "^7.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.0",
    "@biesbjerg/ng2-translate-extract": "^0.6.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.6.1",
    "gulp-rewrite-css": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "latest",
    "lazypipe": "^1.0.1",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.0"
}
}
```

So the issue im encountering is while trying to ng-serve sometimes it fails and always complains about a file error i had in a previous version but i have no more, i even changed the line and it still complains. 
This is the error:
    ERROR in src/app/theme/pages/user/sysuser-list.component.ts(28,34): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SysUser[]'.

Line in question now is:

```
this.sysUserService.getUsers().subscribe(resp => { 
this.sysUsers = resp;
```

Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: You should debug subscribe part, and check that response object. I guess that response is not always in correct form of SysUser[] array. Maybe it is backend issue.

Comment: Ok, let me check that

Comment: Actually i forgot to say the error i get while compiling so is not getting any data :(

Comment: Take also into account that the line it is complaining about no longer has any content referring anything called data

Comment: Then you should check type  of observable return of getUsers() and assure that it is type of SysUser[]. Btw, you can use map() operator to map response to correct type if it not compatible with type that you need for response.